# Why does XMVector4Dot return a vector with the dot product copied to it's components?

Tags: vector, directx-11, dot-product, directxmath

The documentation for XMVector4Dot [lists the return value as a vector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.geometric.xmvector4dot(v=vs.85).aspx). It also states that the dot product is replicated into each component. Given that the dot product is going to be a single value, how does this offer an advantage over just returning float?

The only way I can see to get the value is to do something such as:

```
        XMVECTOR w = { -XMVectorGetX(XMVector4Dot(x, eye)), -XMVectorGetX(XMVector4Dot(y, eye)), -XMVectorGetX(XMVector4Dot(z, eye)), 1 };
```

Which seems unnecessary. Is there another reason I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

This is beneficial with SIMD implementation. CPUs have SIMD instructions (single instruction multiple data).

These instructions work on a different set of registers and going back and forth with regular scalar registers has a significant cost. By using the same vector type for the result of your dot product, it helped keeping the code vector-ised.

Also, it is pretty common practice to splat a scalar value into all the component of a vector and then multiple 4 data with it. You can look at how Array Of Struct versus Structure Of Array ( AOS vs SOA ) influence the design of a SIMD algorithm implementation.

Comment: As noted here, it makes it easier to keep operating in a SIMD mode which is far more efficient than moving between scalar and SIMD operations. Dot-product result is inherently scalar, so this approach means you (a) can keep doing stuff with ``XMVECTOR`` using the result, and (b) you don't have to make sure the computations based on the dot-product have the values in a specific channel. If you want some examples of how this is done, take a look in ``DirectXCollision.inl``.